# Is there a workaround where I can enable Google Safe Search but disable YouTube Safety Mode?

Tags: youtube, google-search

Google recently forced my legacy YouTube account to merge with my Google Account without confirmation. Due to this, I cannot see YouTube comments by default because I prefer enabling Safe Search (strict) on my Google Account. Google mentions how Safe Search and Safety Mode are connected here.

[YouTube Help: Disable or enable Restricted Mode](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/174084)

Is there any workaround that allows me to view comments by default but also keep Safe Search enabled? Creating a new YouTube or Google account don't seem feasible because of how much data (playlists/subscriptions, gmail account) I have entrenched in the services. It would also be a pain to have to keep swapping accounts just to search and watch videos.

Comment: The help page you link to no longer has any information on a linkage between "Safe Search" and "Safety Mode". It only talks about "Restricted Mode" on YouTube. It would appear that the two have been disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

Lock Safe search then disable Safety Mode. You will find that Safety Mode can be disabled while Safe search is locked and it won't be disabled.

Comment: I hope this helps.